# Why do I not get a Notification Sound (NotificationCompat.Builder) SDK26+

Tags: android

Here's my code

```
public static void createNotification(final Context context, final String channelId, final int notificationId, final String content, final String title) {
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_statusbar)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT)
            .setChannelId(channelId);
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(notificationId, builder.build());
}

public static void createNotificationChannel(final Context context, final String channelId) {
    final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    if (notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId) == null) {
        final NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, context.getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("channel_description");
        final AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build();
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        channel.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI, att);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

}
```

I tried almost everything. Getting the URI via AudioManager, setting custom sounds, removed the AudioAttributes and tried the deprecated setDefaults, ...

setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION) does not even vibrate although I've enabled it. USAGE_ALARM does vibrate but does not play the default sound.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could figure it out. Some phones have disabled notification sounds after installation. I had to enable them in "Settings" -> "Notification" -> "Apps" -> your_app -> tick "Enable notification Sounds"